# Unable to use Completable in Room dao interface

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, android-room

I'm trying to use `Completable` in Dao class on `@Insert` annotated methods but when tried to compile the project, I've got this error:

```
error: Methods annotated with @Insert can return either void, long, Long, long[], Long[] or List<Long>.
public abstract io.reactivex.Completable insert(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Here my related codes:

```
@Insert
fun insert(kanal: Kanal): Completable
@Update
fun update(kanal: Kanal): Completable
@Delete
fun delete(kanal: Kanal): Completable
```

And my dependencies:

```
def room_version = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
```

According to this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-rxjava) it's supported by Room.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> @Insert, @Update, and @Delete methods: Room 2.1.0 and higher supports
>   return values of type Completable, Single, and Maybe.

Update your room from `1.1.1` to `2.1.0` or higher and it will work.

Comment: but it's for androidx, I can't use androidx yet. can I return Completable without androidx?

Comment: @DynoCris Unfortunately, all new features will be available in `androidx`. The latest version of  `android.arch.persistence.room` is `1.1.1`. If you want to use `Completable` in Room then you have to migrate to `androidx`

Answer (score 2):

Completable isn't working with `@Insert` in 1.1.1 version of Room. You have to use 2.1.0 version or higher which is only available in Android X.

Make sure to use these dependencies instead of regular `android.arch.persistence.room`:

```
def room_version = "2.2.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Java use annotationProcessor instead of kapt
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

Here's the [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) that provides all of the Android X dependencies of Room.

Answer (score 2):

if you dont want to update the Room's Version, you can try to make a Completable return like this:

```
fun insertSomthing():Completable{
 return Completable.fromAction{
       insert(kanal: Kanal)
 }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

above didnt work for me, here is what i used in oder fix it

```
def room_version = "2.2.6"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
// optional - Test helpers
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```