# Delete method for Room Database is not working

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have a DAO method like this

```java
@Query("DELETE FROM Weather WHERE name = :name")
Completable deleteDataByName(String name);
```

Weather object

```java
@Entity
public class Weather {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String date;
    public String description;
    public String icon;
    etc.
```

Data is not deleted when I call `deleteDataByName` method.
How can I fix it?
There are 16 Weather objects in the database with the same name
How can I delete them?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your query seems correct, how do you ensure the data is not deleted?

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: In next activity I am reading from database and data is exist, not deleted

Comment: Can you post your code where you are calling the `deleteDataByName` function?

Comment: private void getDeleteByName(String city) {
        mAppDatabase.getWeatherDao().deleteDataByName(city);
    }

Comment: maybe, ploblem when I insert to database ?
    @Insert
    Completable insert(List<Weather> data);

Comment: @VadimFedchuk Does your other queries work properly? Something like a SELECT query using the parameter name?

Comment: Please delete these images and paste the gradle files as text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and is resolved by using androidx components. Try with updated room components

```
    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
```

Comment: sorry, but that no fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use a room version higher or equal than 2.1.0
If you are using gradle to build your app go to the project gradle file and add those lines:

```
ext {
    roomVersion = '2.1.0-rc01'
}
```

Then you can update your room dependency in the app gradle with this:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

Also you can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596861/unable-to-use-completable-in-room-dao-interface).

**EDIT**
This is a complete app gradle that you probably need (plus your others dependencies):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
  ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
}
```

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: Can you paste your actuals gradle build scripts? Cause I'm actually working with room and my delete method just works fine

Comment: Alternatively try to remove the return type from your delete method and see if it works, let it be something like this: 
deleteDataByName(String name);

Comment: The last hope would be to query the database for the Weather object that you are tring to delete and than pass it to the delete method: Completable deleteData(Weather weather);

Comment: I add image build.gradle

Comment: Why would you add an image instead of pasting the text?

Comment: Did you finally tried to remove the return type from the delete method?

Answer (score 0):

I read your comment:

```
private void getDeleteByName(String city) { mAppDatabase.getWeatherDao().deleteDataByName(city); } – Vadim Fedchuk 2 days ago
```

You are not calling it right. Your `mAppDatabase.getWeatherDao().deleteDataByName(city)` will do nothing by itself, it's Completable. You have to subscribe to it to make it work.